# What does event_base_dispatch do?

Tags: bitcoind, client

Source code (`src/httpserver.cpp`):

```
static void ThreadHTTP(struct event_base* base, struct evhttp* http)
{
    RenameThread("bitcoin-http");
    LogPrint("http", "Entering http event loop\n");
    event_base_dispatch(base);
    // Event loop will be interrupted by InterruptHTTPServer()
    LogPrint("http", "Exited http event loop\n");
}
```

Can anyone help me understand this portion of logic? In particular

- What is the HTTP magic happening here `event_base_dispatch(base)`?
- Why are we renaming threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event_base_dispatch` is part of libevent, a library that takes events from network sockets, and uses them to call callbacks in your program. To find out what it's calling, you should look at the `struct event_base* base` variable.

```
bool InitHTTPServer()
{
    // [...]
    base = event_base_new(); // XXX RAII
    // [...]
    http = evhttp_new(base); // XXX RAII
    // [...]
    evhttp_set_gencb(http, http_request_cb, NULL);
```

There are three important calls here. `event_base_new` creates the struct that tells `event_base_dispatch` how to handle incoming connections. `evhttp_new` tells libevent to interpret incoming data as the HTTP protocol, instead of passing along raw bytes. `evhttp_set_gencb` tells libevent which function to call when new requests come in. This is where that ends:

```
/** HTTP request callback */
static void http_request_cb(struct evhttp_request* req, void* arg)
```

> Why are we renaming threads?

Debuggging and performance logging.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! As I understand, here we are registering handlers while we are listening to socket connections. But where is the logic which actually causes the invocation of these callback functions? Lets say, I have established connection between 2 nodes `A` and `B` and I want to send a `INV` message from `B` to `A`.

Comment: @Paarth `But where is the logic which actually causes the invocation` Somewhere in libevent, I think. I don't think I understand your question. `Lets say, I have established connection` That's not handled by this code at all. This is JSON-RPC code, and you're looking for the peer to peer code. That's in ProcessMessage in main.cpp on the receiving side, and SendMessages in main.cpp on the sending side. Look for `NetMsgType::INV`

Comment: Thank you once again. So JSON-RPC is used ONLY for communicating between bitcoin-d servers and its client? But the mining nodes individually talk via some other logic to exchange messages (like inv, ack or blk ) etc

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, but ack and blk aren't messages. The closest thing in the p2p protocol to ack and blk is `pong` and `block`.

Comment: Really sorry to bother you again. My background in networks is pretty bad. But where exactly is the socket connection happening for p2p protocol? All the logic I can see in codebase is associated with JSON-RPC in `httpserver.cpp`. The `main.cpp` you had pointed out implicitly boils down to overloaded function `PushMessage`, which uses `BeginMessage` in `net.cpp`. The logic am looking for is how the data in `PushMessage` (or `BeginMessage`) is actually being sent to other nodes. It needs to send the data via some opened socket right? If I am not wrong.

Comment: @Paarth The connection is opened here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7a5040155ed59f8c9c51734bb2ee29f1593eaa6a/src/net.cpp#L1615  The data is sent here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7a5040155ed59f8c9c51734bb2ee29f1593eaa6a/src/net.cpp#L764